# C# JSON.NET - Convert Array to JSON string thats including url

Tags: c#, arrays, json, url, json.net

i want to convert an object to an JSON string. 
The object contains two properties: **Name** and **URL**

```
  WebsiteInfo _wbInfo = new WebsiteInfo();
  _wbInfo.WebsiteName = "MyWebsite";
  _wbInfo.URL = "http://example.com/";

  string _jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_wbInfo);
```

And this is the result:

```
{"WebsiteName":"MyWebsite","URL":"http://example.com/"}
```

So far so good, but if i send this json string to my JSON service, i get the error message "404 Not Found".

This is my complete url:

```
http://localhost:63124/Test/{"WebsiteName":"MyWebsite","URL":"http://example.com/"}
```

If i execute this (without slashes "/") it will work:

```
http://localhost:63124/Test/{"WebsiteName":"MyWebsite","URL":"http:example.com"}
```

Also with escaped slash it will not work:

```
http://localhost:63124/Test/{"WebsiteName":"MyWebsite","URL":"http:%2F%2F/example.com%2F"}
```

This is my JSON-Service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/Test/{WebsiteInfo}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string Test(string WebsiteInfo);
```

Comment: Why you not use POST method instead GET? And send data model not like part of uri, but like content?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you can't send JSON in the way you're attempting here.

your JSON object should be sent in the request body instead.